# Problema para que aplique la misma función a varios botones, un js a un html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como menciono, intento que un .js cambie el formato de unos botones, esto ya lo logre, sin embargo no logro que se aplique a múltiples botones, ojo, no quiero que aplique en todos los elementos button, solo a algunos y si no me equivoco para esto puedo usar class, pero solo lo aplica al primer elemento que se encuentra.

intente usar class para identificar a los botones que  quiero que se les aplique el efecto. de igual forma intente usar id, pero tampoco fun

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>Nombre titulo</title>
    <meta lang="es" dir="ltr">
    <link rel="icon" href="#">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../CV/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <header>
    <ul>
        <li><button class="button1">sombrero</button></li>
        <li><button class="button1">azul</button></li>
        <li><button class="button1">skills</button></li>
        <li><button class="button1">Contact</button></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <hr class="hr1"/>
        <article class="circulo">
            <img src="../CV/Sombrero.png" class="logo_sombrero"/>
        </article>
        <hr class="hr2"/>
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <h5>&copy</h5>
  </footer>
</html>
```

este es el js, donde he intentado usar querySelector, será mejor intentar usar un if para que cambie el elemento, pero si es así no se como hacer esa pregunta, es decir la pregunta correcta seria: ¿como cambiar de une elemento class a otro en función de la condición evaluada?, y si es así, ¿esto no generaría una repetición innecesaria del bucle?, pienso que solo usar un elemento class podría simplificar el proceso para que el js sea lo mas eficiente posible, no se si me explique, gracias.

JS:

```
'use strict'
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { 
 var boton = document.querySelector(".button1");

 boton.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  console.log("entro...");
  boton.style.setProperty("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
  boton.style.setProperty("border-radius", "10%"); 
  boton.style.setProperty("color", "#000000");
 });
 boton.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  console.log("...Salio");
  boton.style.setProperty("background-color", "rgba(240, 248, 255, 0)");
  boton.style.setProperty("border.style", "none");
  boton.style.setProperty("color", "white");
 });
});
```

Pongo el CSS por si esto afecta en algo al funcionamiento de los setProperty del js

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
 display: none;
 }

 header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
 }
ul{
 margin-right: 2%;
 }
li{
 background-color: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.014);
 position: static;
 top: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 float: right;
 border-right: thin solid white;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
button{
 background-color: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0);
 border-style: none;
 color: white;
}
body{
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.781), rgb(46, 46, 47));
 height:500px;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
.welcome{
 margin-top: 15%;
 float:none;
 height:fit-content;
 color: white;
}
hr.hr1{
 border-color: thin black;
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:-1px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-right: 50%;
}
hr.hr2{
 border-color: thin black;
 margin-top: -1px;
 margin-right: 0%;
 margin-left: 50%;
}
.circulo{
 border: thin solid white;
 align-items: center;
 border-radius: 49%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: flex;
 top: 50%;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
.logo_sombrero{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
footer{
 color: white;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando `querySelector` el cual solo actúa en un elemento (el primero elemento encontrado en orden según como se haya encontrado en el DOM). En realidad lo que necesitas es usar `querySelectorAll` el cual te retorna una lista de nodos con todos los elementos que cumplan con el selector buscado.

Para aplicar el **eventListener** a todos estos nodos tienes que iterar sobre ellos y añadir el listener a cada uno de ellos, para eso necesitas convertir la lista a un arreglo, eso lo puedes hacer así

```js
 var botones = [...document.querySelector(".button1")];
```

Luego puedes iterar sobre cada botón así:

```js
botones.forEach((boton) => {
    boton.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        console.log("entro...");
        boton.style.setProperty("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
        boton.style.setProperty("border-radius", "10%");
        boton.style.setProperty("color", "#000000");
    });
    boton.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        console.log("...Salio");
        boton.style.setProperty("background-color", "rgba(240, 248, 255, 0)");
        boton.style.setProperty("border.style", "none");
        boton.style.setProperty("color", "white");
    });
});
```